# Measure code coverage with black box testing

Tags: .net, asp.net, code-coverage

Is there any way or any tool to measure code coverage during black box testing?
I have to measure code coverage from a web application that runs on dot net source code.

Comment: With what? Code coverage tools are specific in what they target. A Python code coverage tool won't do anything with C code, for example.

Comment: this is also very useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Answer (score 1):

There are several code coverage tools that may be of use to you for .NET; however running code coverage against a running application rather than against unit/automated tests is subject to issues (inconsistent reporting) due to user error and also problematic as you have to get your application to talk to the profiler. The commercial offerings will probably be better for you in this regard (as this is a feature they can sell).

You should really be running coverage against a test suite i.e. nunit/mstest - I personally find little benefit of using code coverage tools against an actually running application under a user's (tester/dev/real) control.

Commercial

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) - [IIS and NCover](http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/code-coverage-of-asp-net-applications-on-iis/) instructions

[Semantic Designs](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/LanguageTools/CSharpTools.html)

Open Source

[PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) - no support but you can use iisexpress (sequence and IL coverage).

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) - support for integrating into IIS is in the pipeline; but you can use it against iisexpress (sequence and branch coverage).

All of the above, I believe, instrument the code using profiler API - to get code coverage. Also to examine the coverage against your code (.cs/.vb files) you will probably need the PDB files (as this is where all that IL offset -> source code line information resides).